# Replace an entire line in package.json using bash tools

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I am working on a command line that will install every required node for a nodejs project.

Currently you can do:

```
sudo gen-web-app express
```

and this will genereate everything you need to start developing for expressjs.

I'm working now on

```
sudo gen-web-app reactjs
```

Everything is working except I have to go manually in the package.json and add the startup script to the file.
I know this is possible using SED In BASH, but I need a little help using sed.

This is the file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

I want to replace the following, but I would appreciate a little help :)

```
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

with

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server"
```

Comment: This is the most basic task you can do with `sed`. Care to check its documentation or a quick tutorial? Also, if possible you should avoid `sed` and use a tool capable of understanding the `JSON` format, such as `jq`.

Comment: Don't use a non JSON syntax aware parser like `sed`, use `jq` which is meant for JSON parsing. Can you download and install `jq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download and install jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) - A command line `JSON` syntax aware parser which lets you modify `.json` files. For your example in question.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)    
jq '.scripts.start = "webpack-dev-server" | del(.scripts.test)' input.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" input.json
```

will produce the final `.json` file as

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

You can play with `jq` in a free-playground developed at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/XtbyoZYr8K).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , will look into JQ :) !

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -ie 's/\"test\": \"echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1\"/\"start\": \"webpack-dev-server\"/g' file
$ cat file
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `jq` would be to simply overwrite the value of `.scripts`:

```
jq '.scripts = { start: "webpack-dev-server" }' file.json
```